# Override core files using module prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

Actually I'm a newbie to prestashop,

and I have changes in the following file in these locations

`classes/Product.php`

`src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/ProductController.php`

`src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/form.html.twig`

I have created a module named as **My Kit** while this module is configured all these changes should work..If the module is set to be disabled these changes should not affect in front end(I mean in admin panel)

For this I've created an **`override`** folder in `my_kit` module and place all those above mentioned files into this `my_kit\override` path..

like

`my_kit\override\classes/Product.php`

`my_kit\override\src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/ProductController.php`

`my_kit\override\src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/form.html.twig`

But it won't work for me :(

how should I do this one..

Someone help me out of this..

Comment: Check module enable/disable in override file and if enabled run the override code.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455188/how-to-override-prestashop-core-files/47455726#47455726

Answer (score 0):

You can use php default **copy** function in your main file install function like below.

```
public function install()
{

copy(_PS_ROOT_DIR_."/modules/your module name/classes/Product.php",_PS_ROOT_DIR_."/override/classes/Product.php");

unlink(_PS_ROOT_DIR_."/cache/class_index.php");//because you need to delete this file after override

//Do same like this all other file.


}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how you will work around the part with the custom module (maybe when the module is not configured, you will leave the override classes only defined, and when its configured, you will put the changes there)... still changes in the core files should be done like this - for the Product class:

1. Make a new file in (basefolder)/override/classes/Product.php
2. Define the class ass:

   ```
   class Product extends ProductCore
   ```
3. Do your changes. (override functions, or adding new ones)

Comment: but how those changes are remain only if my particular module is enabled?how does it work??

Comment: You can try adding a new value in the ps_configuration table, so if your module is enabled it would change that value to 1, and when its not the value to 0. Then in the override class u can check it like 
  if(Configuration::get('your_configuration_variable') === 1) add your changes and leave the original function in else clause.

Comment: PS 1.7 manages it automatically. If module is disabled it removes classes from `/override` folder. If you enable module, it copies classes again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override classes from `src` folder

> PrestaShop 1.7 introduces the use of namespaces with its new
>   architecture, and in short, anything that has namespaces cannot be
>   overridden. The legacy architecture can still be overridden, though.
>   But in general, we advise against overriding code. It is better to
>   extend it. Also, overrides are currently forbidden in the
>   Symfony-based pages (namely, the Product page and the Modules page).

http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-faq/#is-there-any-change-planned-to-the-override-system

If you want to override PrestaShop's classes and controllers, you can do it as in previous versions

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors