# How to override prestashop core files

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Can you please explain how to override following core files properly in presatashop. Prestashop 1.7.1.2 allowed only controllers, modal and tpl files in override folder. We can not override src folders in same way.

src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/ProductController.php src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/form.html.twig

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible in Prestashop 1.7. See their post [here](http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-faq/#is-there-any-change-planned-to-the-override-system) : it seems like they want you to use hooks, ie extending not overriding...

Answer (score 2):

From PS 1.7.3, you can override `src` views and controllers in a module.

To override this template file:

`src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/form.html.twig`

You can add it in a module:

`modules/<MY-MODULE>/views/PrestaShop/Admin/Product/form.html.twig`

[Doc PrestaShop for views in a module](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/templating/admin-views)

---

And to override this controller file:

`src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/ProductController.php`

You can add it in global override folder:

`override/PrestaShop/Controllers/Admin/ProductController.php`

Or in a module:

`modules/<MY-MODULE>/override/PrestaShop/Controllers/Admin/ProductController.php`

[Doc PrestaShop for controllers in a module](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/)

Answer (score -1):

PrestaShop give you the ability to override core files, you can check the : [officiel doc](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors)

Comment: this answer is not valid for PS 1.7+

Comment: follow this 1.7 doc, you cannot override "PrestaShop 1.7 introduces the use of namespaces with its new architecture, and in short, anything that has namespaces cannot be overridden."